create a 2D heat map on a triangular mesh with gnuplot
Starting from the coordinates (two first columns) of two triangles and in the third column a temperature for each triangle, I want to draw with gnuplot the two triangles filled with colors associated to the third column (heatmap). The final goal is to use gnuplot to draw a heatmap from a list of triangles (triangular mesh)).
With this simple example,
file1.dat:
# first triangle
0.0 0.0 10.
2.0 0.0 10.
1.0 2.0 10.

# second triangle
2.0 0.0 20.0
6.0 0.0 20.0
5.0 2.0 20.0

I expect gnuplot to draw the two triangles filled with colors associated with the third column. The code I ended up with is:
set pm3d map implicit # possibly with corners2color min
splot 'file1.dat' u 1:2:($3) with pm3d notitle

It leads to only one entity of a single color.

If I rearrange differently the file by having a blank line between each segments of the triangles:
file2.dat:
#first triangle
0. 0. 10.0
2. 0. 10.0

2. 0. 10.0
1. 2. 10.0

1. 2. 10.0
0. 0. 10.0

#second triangle
2. 0. 20.0
6. 0. 20.0

6. 0. 20.0
5. 2. 20.0

5. 2. 20.0
2. 0. 20.0

I get a slightly better image but still not what I want (the second triangle color is not correct, only its segments are)

What am I missing here?

What am I missing here ? .. It's best if you can include a sample of your required output, ideally from your input, but in this case, any sample will help readers avoid having to play "20 questions" with you.  (-;  Good luck!

The simplest way to do this is to treat the data as polygons having 3D coordinates x y z.   By default the z coordinate is used to pick a color from the current palette, which is what you want.  Using your file1.dat as an example and using splot with set view map to show the projection onto the xy plane:
set palette defined (0 "blue", 1 "yellow")
set cbrange [0:30]
set view map
splot "file1.dat" using 1:2:3 with polygons fillcolor  palette



If you have a 2D plot, I would say there is no need to go to 3D, i.e. splot. With splot you might get some hassle with the graph/canvas margins which you don't have with a simple plot. Hence, simply use with filledcurves (check help filledcurves). There is the option closed. Although your data doesn't describe closed triangles, but gnuplot will close them with a straight line from the last to the first point. So, you can use the data as is from your first data example.
Script:
### plotting filled triangles
reset session

$Data <<EOD
# first triangle
0.0 0.0 10.
2.0 0.0 10.
1.0 2.0 10.

# second triangle
2.0 0.0 20.0
6.0 0.0 20.0
5.0 2.0 20.0

# third triangle
3.0 1.0 30.0
4.0 3.0 30.0
1.5 1.5 30.0
EOD

set palette rgb 33,13,10
set key noautotitle
set style fill solid noborder

plot $Data u 1:2:3 w filledcurves closed lc palette z
### end of script

Result:


Thanks Ethan and theoz. I complicated things unecessarily in my first try. Your solutions work very well.

@ChristopheMartin glad to hear. If one of the answers solved your problem please check one of the answers indicating that the questions is answerd and the problem does not stay appearing as unsolved.
